# Java regex - can't start or end with slash or space, and no consecutive slashes

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex with the following requirements:

- can contain alphanumeric chars, spaces and slashes
- cannot start or end with space or slash
- cannot contain consecutive slashes
- can be between 2 and 20 chars in length

I have the following so far:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9/ ]{0,18}[A-Za-z0-9]$
```

I think it covers everything except consecutive slashes. Is there a way to meet this requirement in Java regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that condition using a lookahead at the beginning:

```
^(?!.*//)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9/ ]{0,18}[A-Za-z0-9]$
 ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV1vZ4/1)

The lookahead `(?!.*//)` is [negative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) due to `(?!` and is failing the match once it finds any `//` after any 0+ characters other than a newline (`.*`).

You may use it without `^` and `$` with `String#matches` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/cLiMRQ)):

```
String input = "abc //abc";
if (!input.matches("(?!.*//)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9/ ]{0,18}[A-Za-z0-9]")) { 
        System.out.println("Not matching!");    
}
```

as `String#matches` requires a full string match, but I'd keep the anchors explicit for clarity.